# Windows scheduled Task - Stopping & Starting a service

Tags: windows, services, scheduled-tasks

How can I go by setting up a scheduled task that will cancel a java console and then start it up again?

I need to restart my wowza service because of some java heap allocating memory error that seems to happen every night.

I tried few options but could not get it right.

Comment: type services.msc in run box, locate service you wish to kill, restart, schedule, etc. and perform your actions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) to close the application and then start it again,
put both instructions in a batch file.

Now create a new event using the wizard and carefully configure it.

Try to run the task manually, check the status of it and also try to check the event log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use net.exe start/stop to start and stop services, and sc.exe (XP+) if you need to query/change service config etc